# MongoDB receiving ObjectId("0...0")

Tags: c#, typescript, mongodb, entity-framework, webapi

I am creating a webAPI on chesstournaments. I am writing that in C# (.NET7) using MongoDB Entity Framework. The problem I have is the following:
When inserting a tournament with the reference to a user the MongoDB creates `ObjectId('000000000000000000000000')` instead of the actual reference to the user.

Here is my TournamentModel.cs:

```
public enum TournamentStatus
{
    Planned,
    Ongoing,
    Finished,
}
public enum TournamentType
{
    Classic,
    Rapid,
    Blitz,
    Bullet
}
[Collection("tournaments")]
public class Tournament
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public ObjectId? UserId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Title is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }        
    public string EventUrl { get; set; }        
    public string County { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Status is required")]
    public TournamentStatus Status { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Provide type of tournament")]
    public TournamentType Type {  get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Provide information whether the tournament is FIDE classified")]
    public Boolean IsFide {  get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Provide details for tournament")]
    public TournamentDetails Details { get; set; }        
}
```

Here is Adding logic in TournamentService.cs:

```
public void AddTournament(Tournament newTournament)
{                        
    _BCAContextDb.Tournaments.Add(newTournament);
    _BCAContextDb.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    Console.WriteLine(_BCAContextDb.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
    _BCAContextDb.SaveChanges();
}
```

And here is my Posting logic in TournamentController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Tournament> PostTournament(Tournament tournament)
{            
    _tournamentService.AddTournament(tournament);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTournamentById), new { id = tournament.Id }, tournament);
}
```

Now this is my typescript script that's supposed to shove in a new tournament with a reference to a user:

```
const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
});

let tournament = {
  userId:{},
  title: "string",
  eventUrl: "string",
  county: "string",
  status: 0,
  type: 0,
  isFide: true,
  details: {
    startDate: "2024-03-13T18:53:41.465Z",
    endDate: "2024-03-13T18:53:41.465Z",
    place: "string",
    gameTempo: "string",
    referee: "string",
    organizer: "string",
    roundsTotal: 0,
    roundsEnded: 0,
    gameSystem: "string",
  },
};

const grabData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://localhost:7001/api/user", { httpsAgent: agent });
    const id = response.data[0].id;
    
    console.log(id);
    return id;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error.message);
    throw error;
  }
};

const main = async () => {
  try {
    const userId = await grabData();
    tournament.userId = userId;
    const tournamentToPush = tournament;
    console.log("Tournament pushed:", tournamentToPush);
    const response = await axios.post("https://localhost:7001/api/tournament", tournamentToPush, { httpsAgent: agent });
    console.log("Tournament created:", response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error.message);
  }
};

main();
```

Now the part that I don't understand is that `console.log("Tournament pushed:", tournamentToPush);` logs out properly:

```
Tournament pushed: {
  userId: {
    timestamp: 1710351938,
    machine: 1666371,
    pid: -758,
    increment: 3116068,
    creationTime: '2024-03-13T17:45:38Z'
  },
  title: 'string',
  eventUrl: 'string',
  county: 'string',
  status: 0,
  type: 0,
  isFide: true,
  details: {...}
}
```

However the document in database looks like this:

[image]

and I have no clue what did I do wrong.
All answers and tips are appreciated.

Comment: Check the datatype.  In the tournament class the UserId field is an object id.  I suspect the value received from the get request, and passed to the post is a string representation, not an ObjectId type.

Comment: When I use console.log(typeof id) in my script it logs out object, and that object can be later on visible in the tournament pushed in the field userId. However the object created in the database is not the one that I pushed, but a weird ObjectId with zeros only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an id field for the model to have it auto populate as a new Object Id.

This can be done using the following attribute:

`BsonIdAttribute`

IE:

`[BsonId] public string Id`

Comment: In the database that field is already an ObjectId.